# Can you enable the ILO NIC on HP servers remotely?

Tags: hp, ilo

I suppose I am 99.99% sure it cannot be done since you need either ILO IP or DNS name to connect, but I'm hoping to be proven wrong.

Is there a trick perhaps to enable it via RIBCL and cpqlocfg.exe?

Comment: With Windows running on the HP server, yes?

Comment: No that would be easy using psexec and the hp tool. No OS on it yet, new server.

Comment: Why were the servers deployed without configuring the ILO?

Comment: You say that these servers are "from the latest batch". I'll assume that means that they're brand new. I'll also assume that every and any new server purchased from HP comes with some level of support. If my assumptions are correct then: Call HP.

Comment: The servers can physically have ILO enabled but it's not efficient as there are quite a lot of them hence the reason I'd like to get it done via scripting. PXE might be the only other option it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details about your scenario, here's some thoughts. You need to talk to something, somehow.

Out of the box, the iLO might be enabled and on DHCP (or static IP), so if you have the physical tag, you can get there. If you know that it's been configured and turned off, and there's no OS, you might have a couple of options :

Remote KVM, assuming your infrastructure has it.

PXE booting might be enabled on the machine, in which case you could boot something that has the HP tools in it, like a small Linux, or maybe even SmartStart.

Comment: If all you got is remote IP access to the network, then I think PXE is your next stop.

Comment: I wonder would it be possible to run something like WinPE and have that run a script that enables the ILO NIC? All would need to be automatic of course, but if that image could be pushed via PXE should work right?

Comment: Yes, that's the sort of thing that I meant exactly. Doesn't matter what OS you choose to deliver via PXE, as long as it can do what you want without interaction.

Comment: If you're already familiar with WinPE it just need to run the iLO Online Configuration Utility ([32bit](http://tinyurl.com/baquck6), [64bit](http://tinyurl.com/b38brqt)), you'll probably want [sample scripts](http://tinyurl.com/a7gyhxx) to get you started with the utility. Sorry about the tinyurl links, but HP's links are monstrous.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're talking about HP servers, out of the box the iLO is configured to get an IP via DHCP and have a hostname based on the serial number of the server. The server has this hostname and the default password written either on a removable tag, a sticker on the top of the server, or a pull-out tag on the front panel.

But if your iLO is actually disabled and you have no OS on the server, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Yes usually but the latest batch had some error in the SKU build stage in the factory and they came with ILO disabled :(

Comment: You should hold your rep to the fire for this. Either free tech visits from them to fix each server, or some other consideration for you if you find a decent way to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You should have used a deployment tool if these were new systems before bringing them up in production... [conrep](https://serverfault.com/a/254581/13325), [hponcfg](https://serverfault.com/questions/334424/configuration-of-ilo-port-on-hp-servers/334446#334446), the [HP Service Pack for ProLiant](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/spp/index.html)...

These are all approaches to dealing with batch installations on new HP hardware. You don't specify the server models, though. If Gen8, the [provisioning tool is baked into the server](http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/intelligentprovisioning/index.html).